# tikzpicture node location from top-left of page?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to position a logo at 1cm top, 1cm left. However if I use `(1, -1)` this takes in account the geometry margins. With `(current page.north west)`, I don't have offesets.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, anchor=west]
    \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt] (logo) at (current page.north west) {%
    \includegraphics[height=2cm]{logo.pdf} \\
    Foobar
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I position my node from an absolute position?

Comment: If you want to shift a position, use the shift keys: either `xshift=1cm, yshift=-1cm` or `shift={(1cm, -1cm)}`. That can be done either as options to the `\node` or as options to the `at` coordinate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another possibility: use `\path ... node`

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
    \path (current page.north west) +(1,-1) node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, align=center] (logo) {% \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image} \\
    Foobar
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: It should be noted that in non-overlay cases the bounding box will include that first coordinate which doesn't happen when `[x|y]shift`ing or even `calc`'s `($(current page.north west)+(1,-1)$)` are used.

Answer (score 4):

Apply the `shift` to the `at` parameter:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3.5cm,right=2.5cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay, anchor=west]
    \node[anchor=north west, inner sep=0pt, align=center] (logo) at ([shift={(1cm,-1cm)}]current page.north west) {%
    \includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image} \\
    Foobar
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]